# Underscore - Find from a sorted array of objects

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

Underscore provides the function `sortBy` to sort an array of objects. However once I have this sorted array, is there a way to find an element using binary search? The function `find` does not leverage the fact that the array is sorted, while the function `indexOf` does, but it does not provide a way to specify the sort key.

1. Am I missing something?
2. Is there any other JS library that allows to do this easily?

Comment: Curious: what are you doing that a binary search makes the difference between tractable and unacceptable? How large is your array and what are you doing to it?

Comment: A binary search must be performed on a sorted array. Since you have an array of objects, you will most likely need a custom solution.

Comment: The array itself is about 1000 items, but I need to find items in it many times. So a linear search of this array in a loop may not be very efficient.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The function `_.sortedIndex` is used for a binary search, but is a little more general than your purpose. I would just use it to build a sortedFind, for example:

```
_.sortedFind = function sortedFind(list, item, key) {
    return (_.isEqual(item, list[_.sortedIndex(list, item, key)]));
}
```

Example Usage:

```
// http://jsfiddle.net/w3hzrehy/
_.sortedFind([10, 20, 30, 40, 50], 10); // true

var stooges = [{name: 'moe', age: 40}, {name: 'curly', age: 60}];
_.sortedFind(stooges, {name: 'larry', age: 50}, 'age'); // false
_.sortedFind(stooges, {name: 'curly', age: 60}, 'age'); // true
```

Comment: Thanks. This is very close! I actually wanted to find the index given a value. So `_.sortedFind(stooges, {name: 'curly'}, 'name');` should return the index 1. I believe `_.sortedIndex(stooges, {name: 'curly'}, 'name');` does exactly that although I am not sending it the full item. All I need to do is to check whether the returned index indeed contains the item with name 'curly'. The underscore docs are not very clear on this, but I think this is how it is supposed to work. Can you please confirm?

Comment: @Naresh yes it looks like you are using `sortedIndex` correctly, if you are going to reuse your function, you may want to generalize it for function based and pure value sorts: http://jsfiddle.net/w3hzrehy/18/ (note I had to upgrade underscore for access to the _iteratee() function.)

Answer (score 1):

You aren't missing anything.  It's kind of surprising, isn't it?

Google Closure library does support functions inside of binarySearch (I'm sure there are others):

http://docs.closure-library.googlecode.com/git/namespace_goog_array.html

You would use it just like you'd imagine:

```
var myArray = getPetArray();
goog.array.binarySearch(myArray, 'fido', function(pet) { return pet.name; });
```

If you don't want to drag in yet another library, the source is short and available:

http://docs.closure-library.googlecode.com/git/local_closure_goog_array_array.js.source.html#line989

I cut and paste the important part here in case links change -- just remember to give credit to Google:

```
goog.array.binarySearch = function(arr, target, opt_compareFn) {
  return goog.array.binarySearch_(arr,
  opt_compareFn || goog.array.defaultCompare, false /* isEvaluator */,
  target);
};

goog.array.binarySearch_ = function(arr, compareFn, isEvaluator, opt_target,
opt_selfObj) {
   var left = 0;  // inclusive
   var right = arr.length;  // exclusive
   var found;
   while (left < right) {
     var middle = (left + right) >> 1;
     var compareResult;
     if (isEvaluator) {
       compareResult = compareFn.call(opt_selfObj, arr[middle], middle, arr);
     } else {
       compareResult = compareFn(opt_target, arr[middle]);
     }
     if (compareResult > 0) {
       left = middle + 1;
     } else {
       right = middle;
       // We are looking for the lowest index so we can't return immediately.
       found = !compareResult;
     }
   }
   // left is the index if found, or the insertion point otherwise.
   // ~left is a shorthand for -left - 1.
   return found ? left : ~left;
 };

goog.array.defaultCompare = function(a, b) {
  return a > b ? 1 : a < b ? -1 : 0;
};
```

Comment: Thanks, this is a great solution. However @lossleader's solution was implementable with very little additional effort using underscore, hence I marked that as the accepted answer. Thanks again for your help.